# Contact or application-specific vibration "tone" (pattern)

Tags: contacts, customization, vibration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to customize vibrate patterns?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/is-there-a-way-to-customize-vibrate-patterns)

I want a custom vibration "tone" (pattern) for different callers or applications.

Does Android have any facility for this? Can contacts hold custom information like this?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/is-there-a-way-to-customize-vibrate-patterns/1220#1220

Answer (score 0):

Using the app, Locale, you can use the Contact condition to spot the caller and the Notification plugin action to use a vibration pattern.

There does not appear to be a contact-specific configuration built-in, even in Froyo.