# Is there a way to customize vibrate patterns?

Tags: notifications, ringtone

Like many people my phone is most of the time in silent/vibrate mode. I was wondering if there's a way to assign different vibration patterns for different notifications, just like we do for ringtones and alerts with sounds.
Maybe there's an app that allows us to do that? I couldn't find anything yet.

Answer (score 5):

[SMS Popup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.everythingandroid.smspopup) does vibration patterns on a per contact basis (or for all texts).

[Handcent](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.handcent.nextsms) does it only for all texts.

[Missed Call](http://www.appbrain.com/app/de.anno.android.missedCall) will do vibration patterns for SMS (per contact), phone calls (per contact),  Battery, Calendar events, device storage, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Notification plug-in for Locale, you can set separate vibrate patterns for different conditions.

Answer (score 3):

[Vibromaker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/info.crapsoftware.vibromaker) is has pre-defined patterns.

Answer (score 2):

New app called [WhoIsIt](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handyandy.whoisit.lite) lets you customize the ring/notification audio and vibration.

[Lifehacker review](http://lifehacker.com/#!5785023/whoisit-creates-contact+specific-ringtones-and-vibration-patterns-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

[Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&feature=search_result) lets you create custom vibrate patterns for a variety of simple or complex events including location, either by typing in the pause,pulse,pause,pulse... numbers, or tapping out the pattern on a button

(Llama is free, funded by donations)

Answer (score 1):

[ViBe](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.base2apps.vibes) lets you select one of ten custom vibration patterns to attach to a contact for phone calls and SMS/MMS messages. (There's also a way to unlock and make custom vibration patterns.)

Free in the Market.

([Lifehacker review](http://lifehacker.com/5877529/vibe-lets-you-know-whos-calling-with-custom-vibration-patterns-on-android))