# How do I change vibrate settings on Android

Tags: notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to customize vibrate patterns?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/is-there-a-way-to-customize-vibrate-patterns)

Hi guys, wonder if any of you can help?

I am trying to find out how to change the default vibrate pattern for incoming calls, SMS etc. I know how to create my own custom vibration and have it vibrate onClick() or in my own notifications but do not know where to override the system wide settings. I thought AudioManager.setVibrateSetting would have been it, but that only allows on, off or silent only.

Is there any system wide setting I can change so that I can use my own vibration pattern?

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you can't, because I don't want my phone to ring if I have set it to vibrate or silence.

Comment: If it is possible, I promise I will make my app respect profiles!

Comment: Perhaps this site might help you: http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/customize-android-phone-vibrate-pattern-for-calls-sms-messages/ It seems to be possible. But I have not tried it...

Comment: Whoever upvoted this on StackOverflow needs the ban.